# SQLPLUS Select a Column and Count in the same SELECT statement

Tags: sql, oracle, select, count, sqlplus

I have this simple library checkout table created with the following columns and values inserted into it:

```
insert into CHECKOUT (MemID, Cat#, DateChkOut, DateDue, DateRet) 
    values (4, 'T 430.98 1956', '15-Mar-2011', '14-Jun-2011', '31-May-2011');
insert into CHECKOUT (MemID, Cat#, DateChkOut, DateDue, DateRet) 
    values (12, 'B 125.2 2013', '15-Mar-2011', '14-Jun-2011', NULL);
insert into CHECKOUT (MemID, Cat#, DateChkOut, DateDue, DateRet) 
    values (4, 'T 430.98 1956', '27-Dec-2012', '25-Mar-2013', NULL);
```

For each member, I need to list member id and the number of books ever checked out. I tried using:

```
select distinct MemID, count(distinct Cat#) from CHECKOUT;
```

but receive the error: not a single-group group function. Apparently I can't select a column and a count to display at the same time, but I could be wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Gordon gave you a correct answer.  The part that you didn't know about was pretty fundamental.  That being the case, I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes.

Answer (score 2):

You need a `group by` statement, not a `select distinct`:

```
select MemID, count(distinct Cat#)
from CHECKOUT
group by MemId
```

If you want members who never checked out a book, then you need a `left outer join`:

```
select memID, count(distinct Cat#)
from Members m left outer join
     Checkout co
group by m.MemId
```

The idea behind the `left outer join` is to keep all the rows in the first table, along with the matches in the second table.  This allows you to find members who have no matching rows.

It seems like you are learning SQL.  You should do some studying to better understand the language.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help Gordon! I also need to list those members’ names who never checked out a book (their IDs and Names are stored in a separate table called Member and ID is a PK of checkout's MemID). Is the group by function part of that as well, or is there a different function that is useful to figure that out?